# Update elements background color in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my app, I have 4 components:

- App.vue
- ProfileCardSlider
- ProfileCard
- ColorPicker

The idea is users would be able to update the background color of their ProfileCard using the  element.

I can't work out how I can get the color value from the input and then emit that value up to the parent (App.vue in this case). In App.vue I believe I also need a color data property which this emitted value would then update and pass down as props to the ProfileCard.

These are my two components:

App.vue

```
import ProfileCardSlider from "./components/ProfileCardSlider.vue";
import ColorPicker from "./components/ColorPicker.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    ProfileCardSlider,
    ColorPicker,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      color: "red",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateColor() {
      this.color = color;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <ColorPicker :color="color" @select-color="updateColor" />
  <ProfileCardSlider :color="color" />
</template>
```

ColorPicker.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["color"],
  methods: {
    selectColor(color) {
     this.$emit('update-color', color)
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="color__picker">
    <h2 class="color__picker--title">Card background colour:</h2>
    <input type="color" @change="selectColor" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html) and [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html) in the correct way can help achieve this.

1. In your `App.vue`, use the color data property as hex (best practice to use in props), i.e #000000, and bind the color property to v-model to `ColorPicker` component.
2. Then in `ColorPicker` component, use the value prop which is the v-model binding from `App.vue`, and emit an input event on color input updating.
3. At last, listen to the color-changing event in `App.vue` to pass the updated color to `ProfileCardSlider.vue`.

So, the final code should be-

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ColorPicker v-model="color" @input="updateColor" />
    <ProfileCardSlider :color="color" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProfileCardSlider from "./components/ProfileCardSlider.vue";
import ColorPicker from "./components/ColorPicker.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",

  data() {
    return {
      color: "#ffffff",
    };
  },

  components: {
    ProfileCardSlider,
    ColorPicker,
  },

  methods: {
    updateColor(color) {
      this.color = color;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**ColorPicker.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="color__picker">
    <h2 class="color__picker--title">Card background colour:</h2>
    <input
      type="color"
      :value="value"
      @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ColorPicker",

  props: ["value"]
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**ProfileSlider.vue**
(I take some dummy code for this component as you didn't mention in the question but the logic would be the same.)

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="container" :style="{ background: color }">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ProfileCardSlider",

  props: {
    color: {
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 40%;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
</style>
```

You should see that when you will change the color from the color input which is inside `ColorPicker.vue`, the card inside `ProfileSlider.vue` will have an updated color.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! That's working as I expect now.